# Inline string split to place comma separated values as CSS classes in View

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, split, each

I have a field in my table like:

```
tank, troublesome, athletic, powerback
```

That's a single string.

I'd like to comma separate these values and place them as CSS classes for an element. Here's my attempt:

```
<a href="<%= player_path(player) %>" class="player-item <% players.roles.split(",").each do |role| print role end %>">
```

But I get:

```
<a href="/players/1" class="player-item ">
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just replace the commas with nothing:

```
<a href="<%= player_path(player) %>" class="player-item <% player.roles.gsub(',', '') %>">
```

But I think there is a better solution that would involve refactoring your database. Having fields of comma delimited values is almost never a good idea :) but that is a different story.

Comment: I agree, but in this case it's a path worth taking. Having a third table for `Player <> PlayerRoles <> Role` would be extreme overkill.

Comment: Are you sure `player.roles` is what you think it is? Maybe you should output that and make sure.

Comment: Triple checked and if I just write: `<%= player.roles.split(",") %>` I get `["tank", "etc", "etc", "etc"]`.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to tell you. Here is an example of the gsub: http://codepad.org/Iz3kwWWD

Comment: If your split is giving that output, you can do: `player.roles.split(',').join(' ')`. Not sure why gsub wouldn't be working, splitting and then joining seems like a workaround solution, but it will work nonetheless.